# How can I change an image in Excel using a macro that reads a cell and matches it with the image file name?

Tags: excel, vba, image, jpeg

My idea is to write a macro which is assigned to a button that does the same thing as right-clicking the image and using "Change picture..." and then uses information in a cell to find the correct picture (Lastname, firstname.jpg). Having never worked with excel macros before, you can imagine my dilemma.

Lets say all the pictures are stored under this file path: C:\MyLocalData\hendrik.voelker\Pictures\Portraits

and all use this naming convention:
LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME.JPG

If someone could help me out with this issue that would be amazing! Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I now have the following code for an ActiveX Control image:

```
Sub New_Pic()
Dim strPath As String, strFile As String

strPath = "C:\MyLocalData\john.smith\Pictures\Portraits\"
strFile = Range("M15").Value & ".jpg"

If Len(Dir(strPath & strFile)) Then
    ActiveSheet.Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
    ActiveSheet.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(strPath & strFile)
Else
    MsgBox strFile, vbExclamation, "Image Not Found"
End If
```

End Sub

But the picture inserts in a landscape rather than the desired portrait orientation. I would also like a black border. Any ideas on these two issues?

Comment: If you don't try to accomplish this and provide the code you have tried, and what is the problem. This question will probably be closed just like your previous question. You could try recording a macro while doing the actions you describe in your question.

Comment: @GMalc thanks for the tip! I'm super new to macros and forums so I'm continuously learning. Unfortunately I don't think recording a macro will be much help as it probably can't record the I'm typing the person's name into the search bar when finding their picture.